# Do the incomplete gamma functions have reflection formulas?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

Euler gave this reflection formula for the gamma function:

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$

My question - do the lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma(s,x)$ and the upper incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(s,x)$ have reflection formulas (and if so, what are they)?